# Systemd.service LOAD STATE SUB Meanings

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I'm trying to better understand the state of units in my system.

I've read the systemd and systemctl man pages, and I understand that systemd has three high level state components for a unit - `LOAD`, `ACTIVE`, and `SUB`.

Within those, the `LOAD` state seems fairly simple to comprehend, and is relatively clearly described in prose in the man page.

The `ACTIVE` state seems slightly more complicated, and it's slightly unclear to me when exactly a .service unit would be considered `active` vs. `activating`, for example.  Reading the systemd.service man page however, seems to clarify that the true meaning here may be dependent on service type and other factors?

Finally the `SUB` states.  Per the man pages, I can enumerate them (with , and there are a bunch available for a `.service` unit.  Some of them seem to be fairly self-descriptive, but naming is hard, and so the ones that seem clear may not mean what I think they do, and there are some that I have not been able to guess at what they mean.

Are there concrete, universal definitions of these (`ACTIVE` and `SUB`) states, and what transitions happen between them under what circumstances?  Can you help me understand them?

Another, possibly more basic question - are there fixed relationships between the `ACTIVE` and `SUB` state columns?  That is, if I know my service to be in a certain `SUB` state, do I know there could only be one possible `ACTIVE` state at that time? How can I determine that mapping (if it exists)?